# How can i make my PHPBB3 Forum custom header logo link back to my main website?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpbb, phpbb3

How can i make my PHPBB3 Forum custom header logo link back to my main website?

Step by step instructions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open

phpbbroot/styles/prosilver/template/overall_header.html

find

```
 <a href="{U_INDEX}" title="{L_INDEX}" id="logo">{SITE_LOGO_IMG}</a>
```

Replace {U_INDEX} with a link to your site.

Just to add, Make sure you log into your forums afterwards and then go to the ACP(Administrator Control Panel) > Styles > Templates > Prosilver ( or whatever style you picked) > Refresh > Confirm yes.